# Removal of one value in an array in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a few methods and interfaces in this one. What i need is for the method I'm making to just simply remove 1 value in an array of attributes. All of the stuff here was previously created by someone else, and I'm just creating the removal part for the attribute to be removed. At any rate, the method that does the profile attribute work and sets the value does some work on the back end. I have a method for a UserProfileAttributeSetRequest that looks like this:

```
public UserProfileAttributeSetRequest()
    {
    }


public UserProfileAttributeSetRequest(Guid userIdentifier, Dictionary<string, string> profileAttributes)
    {
        UserIdentifier = userIdentifier;
        ProfileAttributes = profileAttributes;
    }
```

This fires a method on the back end that will take in the information being passed to it and change whatever needs to be changed. The method I'm building in the controller probably needs some work, I'm still fairly new to MVC, but here's what I've got:

```
public ActionResult RemoveEmployeeID(UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        User usr = UserManager.GetUser(userInfo.UserGuid);
        var empID = usr.ProfileAttributes.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ProfileAttributeID == 3);
        usr.ProfileAttributes.Remove(empID);
        UserProfileAttributeSetRequest upd = new UserProfileAttributeSetRequest();

    }
```

I'm grabbing the complete user, and isolating the single attribute I want to be changed, but the Request complains when I put any parameters in it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  What does the Request say when it complains?

Comment: It's not the request itself that complains, when i put paramaters in the UserProfileAttributeSetRequest that it's asking for, because on the back side it's set up to receive a Dictionary, how do i pass a single value back to remove?

Comment: If `empID` is returning correctly, the `Remove(empID)` should work.   But you also need to call the `Update` or `Save` method after you remove it.  Try adding `UserManager.Update(usr);` after you remove it.

Comment: that's what the UserProfileAttributeSetRequest is for, that fires some back end logic that sends the update to the DB. the UserManager.Update(usr); does not work. the UserProfileAttributeSetRequest() accepts the userInfo.UserGuid just fine, but complains when i try to pass it the single attribute i'm trying to change because it's a Dictionary<string, string> on the back side.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var emp = usr.ProfileAttributes.Where(e => e.ProfileAttributeID == 3).FirstOrDefault();
usr.ProfileAttributes.Remove(emp);
```

you have to update the database after removing the item.